# JavaFX - NullPointerException : Location is required

Tags: java, javafx

I have an application being executed on one stage during its lifetime. The stage has a scene set on a HBox. The HBox contains two anchorpanes which display the controls and the content.

Initially, when I start the application, the stage is set, the scenes are loaded, and the controls are rendered just fine. When a button is clicked, I want to replace one of the anchorpanes with another anchorpane saved as a separate FXML file with its own controller.

I am doing this by getting the stage and completely replacing the scene by creating another HBox and placing the anchorpanes there.

This is where the problem is: When the button is clicked, I get a "Location is required" exception. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE.

Here is the main method:

```
public class _Application extends javafx.application.Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException
    {
        HBox root = new HBox();

        AnchorPane sidebar = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("Sidebars/ReceptionistSidebar-View.fxml")));
        AnchorPane appointmentMain = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("Receptionist/Appointments/NewAppointment-View.fxml")));

        root.getChildren().add(sidebar);
        root.getChildren().add(appointmentMain);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the button:

```
public class CreateNewPatientController
{
    @Override
    public void onCancel_ButtonClick() throws IOException
    {
        //Get the stage and scene
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) anchorPane_CreateNewPatient.getScene().getWindow();
        Scene a = currentStage.getScene();

        //Create a new HBox
        HBox root = new HBox();
    
        //Load the anchorpane FXML files
        AnchorPane sidebar = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Sidebars/ReceptionistSidebar-View.fxml"));
        AnchorPane appointmentMain = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Receptionist/CreateNewPatient-View.fxml"));

        //Add the containers to the root
        root.getChildren().add(sidebar);
        root.getChildren().add(appointmentMain);

        //set root to scene and stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        currentStage.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

These are my file structures:

[image]

Comment: When providing code, include the package (and imports).  You are loading files relative to the package, so the package is important.  In any case follow the [lookup guide on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other) and it's troubleshooting section, as well as the [Eden guide](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/).

Comment: A little off-topic, but creating a new Scene and rebuilding FMXL layouts to populate it is just about the worse way that you could approach this.  Build you layouts just once, and put the two right side panes into something like a StackPane and then manipulate their visibility to show/hide them.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue is with how you are trying to load the FXML files in the `CreateNewPatientController class`. The `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` method might not be able to locate the FXML files properly.

Try using the `getClass().getResource()` method directly, without the `getClassLoader()` part. Also, make sure that the paths you provide are correct.